# Cannot import gradle project into another gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, gradle-dependencies

**I have the following Windows directory structure for my 2 gradle projects:**

```
bitbucket/
    users-dashboard/
        backend/
            users-data/
                build.gradle
                settings.gradle
    common-util/
        common-util/
            build.gradle
            settings.gradle
```

And I would like to you use the **common-util project (as a dependency)** into the **users-data** project.

I am trying the following without succeed!

***users-data/settings.gradle***

```
include ':common-util'
project(':common-util').projectDir = new File('../../../common-util/common-util')
```

***users-data/build.gradle***

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common-util')
}
```

***common-util/settings.gradle***

```
rootProject.name = 'common-util'
```

Please help!

***Getting this error:***

```
Project with path ':common-util' could not be found in project ':users-data'.
```

Comment: Project dependencies only work for sub projects within the same gradle project. You can declare a dependency normally and publish locally the common-util project.